# I have a problem using texmaker on a external monitor

Tags: texmaker

I am using a laptop with a 4k screen. Texmaker works perfectly on it. Recently I got a monitor with a 1080p screen and when I link the monitor and extend the screen, the texmaker becomes blurry on the external monitor (The reason I bought it is that I want to look at other files such as a pdf file  and type on the external monitor at the same time). It is still fine if I drag the interface back to my laptop but as I move it to the external monitor it becomes not clear: the fonts are small, the pdf is blurry. It also looks fine if I choose to  duplicate the screen instead of extending it. Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks in advance. (I am using Win10)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I am not sure to which extent this is really a LaTeX problem/question. You may first want to check if this is specific to texmaker, or if other applications have the same problem.

Comment: Hi! I just tried to use some other applications such as Stata, Pycharm, RStudio, Eclipse, Matlab. It turns out that some of them works well (Pycharm, Eclipse, Matlab) and the rest don't. Either fonts are too small, too big, or there is a problem with the GUI. Applications such as Mail, Chrome, are all fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Operating System your `Scale and Layout` settings for each monitor may need adjusting in `Display` `Advanced scaling settings` or `Resolution`. On some systems it is possible to adjust on a per application basis, however when using 2 or more monitors I  focus my working on the best one and keep all others at the default recommended resolution and scale (usually 100%) then use zoom to adjust e.g. enlarging details. This reduces "fuzziness" which is usually down to "font smoothing"
If your using a mac see [mac-screen-blurry](http://osxdaily.com/2012/06/09/mac-screen-blurry-optimize-troubleshoot-font-smoothing-os-x/)

There are several ways this dpi issue can be changed in some TeX editors, so for example TeXmaker version 5 (64bit) is scalable and has an start-up option  -dpiscale 2.0 (Note **not** 200 like I tried :-) you will neeed to experiment for your optimum value between 1.0 and say 3.0, unfortunately I don't know how it will behave so 1.333 may work, please let us know.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response! I just tried to set scaling and I just found one solution (not perfect) to my problem. On my laptop the scaling used to be 250% and when I set the external monitor to be the main display, and change the scaling of my laptop to be 100%, and then use texmaker on the external screen, the pdf becomes clear. But the fonts and icons on the laptop becomes small. I guess I will just have to make this change everytime I want to use latex and since other applications are fine, this might not be very troublesome I hope.

Comment: Rather than 250 (or even 150) you may have had better results with 200 since that = exactly 2 times thus pixelated fonts may look "blocky" but not "fuzzy"

Comment: `-dpiscale` is not a provided option for macs.